# Is there some way of telling the IntelliJ IDEs like PyCharm that a specific file is of a specific format?

Tags: intellij-idea

For instance I can have two files with the same file ending:

- nginx.conf
- ossec.conf

The first one is in nginx format, the second is XML. How do I force different highlights for each without renaming the files?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the template data language for the files in the project settings might help: (See point 3.)

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Syntax+highlighting+of+PHP+inside+JavaScript+%28and+other+languages%29